# Codeigniter "base_url" can't work

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to connect bootstrap CSS file. can't work properly

controller code Welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Login Home";
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
}
```

my views code home.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login Home</title><link href="http://[::1]/ci/register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head><body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>welcome</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `base_url` in `config/config.php` file first as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

Then

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Best practice is put your css files in `assets` directory (create `assets` folder) in root then link as (Assuming your css file at `assets/css`)

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

put your bootstrap css folder out side application folder.i.e in your root folder

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `base_url()` in codeigniter.You have to load `url` helper in your controller first.Like this.for more see here [Url Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
public function index()
    {
       $this->load->helper('url'); //loads url helper
        $data['title'] = "Login Home";
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
```

Then in your view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $title;?></title><!--Echo title here -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet"><!--use base_url here -->

</head><body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>welcome</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

And don;t forget to set `base_url` in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

Hope it woks fine

Comment: @Aravinth E don;t forget load `helper`.

Comment: @Aravinth E  try loading at controller.

Answer (score 0):

First things first base_url() is in the url helper, I suggest adding this to always be loaded (you'll use it alot)...

To file `application / config / autoload.php` Add/change this (around line 88:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array(
'url');
```

I strongly suggest setting up your public files into a public folder, this includes index.php..

your main folder structure would then be

```
/
/application/
/public/
    /index.html
    /css/
    /js/
    /lib/
/system/
```

All you do is create the folder under your main directory and move index.php into it.

then edit the index.php file in these areas:

```
$system_path = '../system';

$application_folder = '../application';
```

Then change your public folder in your webserver (apache virtual host (or ust public directory), etc) to point to public folder `http://localhost/ci/public`

Probably a bit more than what you are after, however its much more secure and every file wont need `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` at the top to prevent direct access to the files.

You would then just reference your css to that direct path as you would to a normal file in your structure... e.g. :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_path('/css/boostrap.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I suggest building a helper to do this, it becomes really annoying loading assets dynamically (additional page-specific styles / javascript files)